# .irbrc file not loaded by rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to get "rails console" to load .irbrc? Or am I supposed to use something else?

Comment: If your `rails console` comes up with a prompt that says `pry(main)`, use `.pryrc` instead.

Comment: I found this question when trying to diagnose my own issue. Turns out I did not have `.irbrc` in `~/`. Once I put it there (or rather simlinked) it worked exactly as expected. Double check just so you do not look foolish like I did :-P

Answer (score 15):

`rails console` by default loads `~/.irbrc`, so I don't really understand your question. It will, however, fail silently (and do not load it) if there are some errors in this file.

One example of such error is requiring gems not defined in the Gemfile (for Rails3 + Bundler) and not rescuing from LoadErrors (or expecting the require to "just work").

Comment: I was just playing around with this and it turns out that if I add a .irbrc file to the root of a project, it won't work unless I also have a ~/.irbrc file.

Answer (score 0):

`rails c` does not load any other `.irbrc` but from the current user's home (`~`).

See https://gist.github.com/railsbros-dirk/719848

You can tweak your rails `application.rb` to load the root `.irbrc` file if present.

Comment: how can we change application.rb to load .irbrc for project's root folder?

Comment: in application.rb, `console do ARGV.push('-r', root.join('.irbrc.rb')) end`